# Two IDs matching one causing duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to inner join however I keep getting this duplicate pop up where there are two job IDs matching one Invoice ID (inner joined with a middle table that links both).

I want to only get 1 invoice id and summing the total despite 2 job ids matching it.

Basically there is AINVOICEID (table:Invoice ) matching ABINVOICEID (table:INLines) and inside the INLines table, it contains ARJOBID that matches the JOBID in Jobs.

```
Select distinct sum(totalBASE) as InvoiceTotal,
       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, InvDate), 0)
from (select distinct left(JOBID,5)as JOBID 
      from jobs 
      group by JOBID
      ) jobs
inner join (select distinct ABINVOICEID, left(ARLJOBID,5) as arljobid 
            from INLines
            group by ARLJOBID, ABINVOICEID
            )  INLines
on left(ARLJOBID,5) = left(JOBID,5)
inner join (select distinct AINVOICEID
                   , sum(totalBASE) as totalBASE
                   , InvDate 
               from Invoice 
               group by AINVOICEID, InvDate
            )  Invoice 
on AINVOICEID = ABINVOICEID
where left(JOBID ,5)=left(ARLJOBID,5) and AINVOICEID = ABINVOICEID 
and InvDate between '05/01/2022' AND '05/31/2022'
group by left(JOBID ,5), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, InvDate), 0)
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. Looking at the above, you appear to have a problem with your `GROUP BY` (you are also grouping on `left(JOBID ,5)`) in the outer query. As for your inner queries, it's a mixed bag. It seems you don't understand what both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` do.

Comment: `left(ARLJOBID,5) = left(JOBID,5)` ? This seems like a disaster waiting to happen. Assuming you have numeric job IDs stored in a char-based column (which, unfortunately, I've seen all too often), what happens when you get to 100000 jobs?

Comment: Help everyone help you. Start by creating short but not cryptic aliases for every table and using the appropriate alias for **every** column reference. Then explain the actual relationship among your three tables. Is there no FK between INLines and jobs? Explain why you focus on the first 5 characters in multiple places. Is AINVOICEID the PK of Invoice?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to try and make sense of what you're asking without an example of the output that you're getting and what the expected output is.

However, I think you're wanting something like this:

```
SELECT I.AINVOICEID, SUM(I.totalBASE) AS totalBASE, InvDate
FROM Invoice I  INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT L.ABINVOICEID, J.JOBID
    FROM INLines L INNER JOIN
        Jobs J ON L.ARLJOBID = J.JOBID
    GROUP BY L.ABINVOICEID, J.JOBID
) LJ ON I.AINVOICEID = L.ABINVOICEID
WHERE I.InvDate BETWEEN '05/01/2022' AND '05/31/2022'
GROUP BY I.AINVOICEID, InvDate
```

This is based on what your SQL query which doesn't really look like it needs to JOIN on the INLines or Jobs table because you're getting everything you need from the Invoice table in the SELECT ?

If this isn't what you're after, if you can elaborate a bit more, then the community on here should be able to better assist with your question.